# C# - Jint Generic Methods

Tags: c#, generics, methods, jint

I am new to using Jint (the Javascript Interpreter for .NET) and am trying to gain a better understanding of the complete functionality. Looking at the documentation, I see support of Generic types like so:

```
jint> var ListOfString = System.Collections.Generic.List(System.String);
jint> var list = new ListOfString();
jint> list.Add('foo');
```

I do not see anywhere any mention of use of methods that take a generic parameter. For instance, take the C# method:

```
public T Get<T>(T t) => t;
```

When I run the following script in Jint I get a `JSValue.Value` of `False (bool)` with a type of `string` whenever a value of `"test"` is expected.

```
Get<System.String>("test");
```

Is calling a method with generics such as this possible in Jint?

Comment: Hi. I suggest you try ` jint> var v = list.ConvertAll<double>(x => (double)x);` and then if it doesn't work, edit this question to ask why.

Comment: I apologize, I have updated the question to show my result when I try in Jint.

Comment: No worries. Have a great day.